# Three SQL tables or one?

Tags: sql, database-schema

I have a choice of creating three tables with identical structure but different content or one table with all of the data and one additional column that distinguishes the data. Each table will have about 10,000 rows in it, and it will be used exclusively for looking up data. The key design criteria is speed of lookup, so which is faster: three tables with 10K rows each or one table with 30K rows, or is there no substantive difference? Note: all columns that will be used as query parameters will have indices.

Comment: More info would be useful, but sounds to me if you have three different types of data, then three different tables.

Comment: All columns in each of the three data sources are identical

Comment: You might find *PARTITIONING* a useful concept if your DB supports it (e.g., Postgres). Sounds like this may be your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no substantial difference between 10k or 30k rows in any modern RDBMS in terms of lookup time. In any case not enough difference to warrant the de-normalization. Indexed qualifier column is a common approach for such a design.

The only time you may consider de-normalizing if your update pattern affects a limited set of data that you can put in a "short" table (say, today's messages in social network) with few(er) indexes for fast inserts/updates and there is a background process transferring the stabilized updates to a large, fully indexed table. The case were you really win *during write operations* will be a dramatic one though, with very particular and unfortunate requirements. RDBMS engines are sophisticated enough to handle most of the simple scenarios in very efficient way. 30k or rows does not sound like a candidate.

If still in doubt, it is very easy to write a test to check on your particular database / system setup. I think if you post your findings here with real data, it will be a useful info for everyone in your steps.

Comment: The table(s) will be completely regenerated every quarter and will be read-only from that point forward, so I am concerned only with query speed. Updating is a non-issue.

Comment: The tables don't exist yet, but once they do, I will run some tests as you suggest... and post the findings.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the speed issue, which the other posters have covered and I agree with, you should also take into consideration the business model that your are replicating in your database, as this may affect the maintenance cost of your solution.

If is it possible that the 3 'things' may turn into 4, and you have chosen the separate table path, then you will have to add another table. Whereas if you choose the discriminator path then it is as simple as coming up with a new discriminator.

However, if you choose the discriminator path and then new requirements dictate that one of 'things' has more data to store then you are going to have to add extra columns to your table which have no relevance to the other 'things'.

I cannot say which is the right way to go, as only you know your business model.